# Showing logged in state with spring and tiles

Tags: java, spring, state, apache-tiles

I am trying to understand the proper way to change the look of page depending on some logic with spring and tiles. For example if a user is viewing a page before logging in and then after logging in they might see some different navigation or actions. Or if a users permissions has changed. Should I just setup a different tile definition for each different state a user might see and then have the controller run the logic to see which definition it should be returning? This seems like the number of tile view definitions can grow very quickly. Is this just the way it is done or is there some other way that handles this simpler.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring security (you tagged your question with spring) the [spring security tag lib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) might be an option:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li>
    <a href="..">Everyone can see this link</a>
  </li>
  <sec:authorize access="hasRole('SomeRole')">
    <li> 
      <a href="..">Only users with role SomeRole can see this link</a>    
    </li>    
  </sec:authorize>
</ul>
```

For simple things like some additional buttons within the navigation this works fine.

But be aware that this only toggles the visibility of the links in the view. You still have to protect your controllers/services to make sure only logged in users can access them.